# Update UI With Live Data & Not MutableLiveData - Room Database

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-mvvm

So i have this Dao where i have declared a LiveData Method.

```js
@Dao
public interface EarthquakeDao {

    @Insert
    public void insert(Properties properties);

    @Query("select * from properties")
    public LiveData<List<Properties>> getAllProperties();

}
```

I have a sortByTitle method in my ViewModel.

```js
    public void sortByTitle(){
            Collections.sort(propertiesList.getValue(), new Comparator<Properties>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Properties o1, Properties o2) {
                    return o1.title.compareTo(o2.title);

                }
            });
            propertiesList.postValue(featuresList.getValue());
    }
```

Since the `propertiesList` is `LiveData` rather than `MutableLiveData` then i am not able to update the UI by using the `postValue` method.

[image]

In order to update the UI, i need to use `MutableLiveData`, and on the other hand...my database gives me a `LiveData` Object. So i am unable to achieve this.

Also, i cant make Dao's method a `MutableLiveData`, i know that.

Then how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply `map` the `LiveData` coming from **Room**. For example:

```
public LiveData<List<Properties>> properties = Transformations.map(propertiesList, list -> {
  return sort(list);
})
```

See [Transformations.map](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#map) for more information

Comment: Is there a way we can do it in Java?

Comment: Yes, should work with the above, you should just replace the `sort()` with your sorting method